# allow website content to become hidden when browser is made smaller instead of just compressed

Tags: css

I am trying to make my website "roll up" when the browser is made smaller. Currently everything just compresses on top of itself? [Link to php and css](http://jsfiddle.net/emily8282/NCtQt/)

The code that likely has something to do with it is:

```
* {margin:0;padding:0;} 

html {overflow-y:auto; 
overflow-x: auto; }

html, body {height: 100%;}

#wrap {min-height: 100%;}

#main {overflow:auto;
top: 79px;
padding-bottom: 79px;
position:relative;}
```

Comment: Check out CSS media queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use media query to achieve this.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 420px){
    body {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

What the above does is, whenever your screen reaches width of 420px or lower then all your content inside the body element will be hidden.

More info on media queries here:-

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries